# Why does replacing a substring with a colored string from the colored crate not work?

Tags: string, rust

I'm trying to replace all the occurrences of a given string with a colorized version:

```
extern crate colored; // 1.6.1

use colored::Colorize;

fn print_found_line(x: &i32, line: &String, found: &str) {
    let mut line_to_print: String = line.clone();

    println!("{}", found.red()); // work
    line_to_print = line_to_print.replace(found, found.red().as_ref());
    println!("[{}] {}", x.to_string().blue(), line_to_print); // the found string replaced is not red
}

fn main() {}
```

The first `println!` works as intended and prints the text in red, but the second `println!` does not work as intended and prints the text in the default color.

It seems that the string literal loses the color information. I want to find a `replace` equivalent that prints the text as I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ColoredString` implements `Deref<Target = str>`, but the returned `&str` doesn't include any color information. You can see this by printing out the dereferenced string:

```
println!("{}", found.red().as_ref() as &str);
```

It appears that the correct thing to do is to convert the colored text into a `String` and use that for formatting.

Additionally:

- Taking a `&String` is useless.
- Cloning the `String` before replacing it is useless

```
fn print_found_line(x: &i32, line: &str, found: &str) {
    let line_to_print = line.replace(found, &found.red().to_string());
    println!("[{}] {}", x.to_string().blue(), line_to_print);
}
```

See also:

- [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec) or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried with a simple to_string() before but it wasn't compiling as the 'to' parameter was not a &str. I must have miss something obvious at that moment.

I accepted your answer and everything is working as intended.